# Custom keys with NERDComment plugin and remapped Leader?

Tags: vim, vi

I'm trying to set up the NERDComment plugin in vim, but I'm having some trouble with the keys. I'd like to set the basic toggle functionality (comment a line if it's uncommented, uncomment if it's commented) to be c. The problem is that I've remapped the Leader to be `,`, which is the same key that NERD wants for all of it's hotkeys. Anyone have any idea as to how to set this up?

Answer (score 14):

Just call NERDComment function in your mapping. For example, my mapping to comment the current line:

```
inoremap ,c <C-o>:call NERDComment(0,"toggle")<C-m>
```

Here's a breakdown of how this vim remap works.

The `i` in inoremap means that the remap only applies in insert mode.

The `noremap` means that the remap can't be overridden later in your .vimrc file by accident, or by a plugin.

The `,c` is the key combination that triggers the key map.

The `<C-o>` temporarily takes you out of insert mode for one command, so the next section of the remap can call the NERDComment function.

The `:call NERDComment(0,"toggle")` is the NERDComment function being called.

Then `<C-m>` is another way of saying carriage return, which executes the command.

Comment: Could you give a further explanation on that line of code?

Comment: I also needed this line in my `.vimrc` in order for this to work: `let g:NERDCreateDefaultMappings = 0`

Comment: Thank you for breaking down the vim syntax it was very helpful.

Comment: In the newer version `NERDComment(0, "toggle")` is deprecated and should be replaced with: `call nerdcommenter#Comment(0,"toggle")`

Answer (score 11):

If you want the comment shortcut to work in normal mode and visual mode, but not in insert mode where it might do something weird when you try to type a comma, you can use the following remaps:

```
nnoremap ,c :call NERDComment(0,"toggle")<CR>
vnoremap ,c :call NERDComment(0,"toggle")<CR>
```

Answer (score 4):

documented method of remapping key is located here:
[remapping documentation](https://github.com/preservim/nerdcommenter/blob/c62e618a1ab5a50a4028e3296500ba29d9b033d8/doc/NERD_commenter.txt#L872)

[reference](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8333/configure-custom-key-mapping-for-plugin-actions)

```
map <leader>d <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle

"silently rejects remap will not work
nnoremap <leader>d <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle
```

I fell into the [pitfall](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/dh5734/how_to_remap_keys_in_nerdcommenter/) of attempting to use "nnoremap" to remap on my first attempt resulting in unresponsive mapping. You must use "map", "nmap", etc to properly remap the function

Answer (score 2):

```
:map <C-z> <plug>NERDCommenterToggle
```

Maps 'toggle comments' to ctrl+z